How to list private supabase bucket files?
I am working on a Vue3 application using Supabase for authentication and storage.
I set up a private bucket named "sounds" and configured policies to allow access only to authenticated users.
However, trying to list the items in the bucket returns an empty list
My authentication method:
//located @/api/authentication.ts
import { supabase } from './supabase';

export async function signInWithEmail() {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
        //YES, this dummy auth works
        email: "test@test.de",
        password: "test",
    });
    if (error) {
        console.error('Error during sign in:', error);
        return null;
    }
    return data.user;
}

Currently I simply put everything in my App.vue:
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { supabase } from '@/api/supabase';
import { signInWithEmail } from '@/api/authentication'

onMounted(async () => {
  const user = await signInWithEmail()
  console.log(user)
  const { data, error } = await supabase.storage.from('sounds').list();
  if (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching sounds:', error);
    return [];
  }
  console.log(data)
});


And here is the policy I have set on the Supabase dashboard for the "sounds" bucket:
create policy "Allow read to authenticated users"
    on storage.objects for select
    using (auth.role() = 'authenticated' and bucket_id = 'sounds');

Trying to fetch sounds returns an empty list.
What is causing to return an empty list, and how to display the "Terminator.mp3" actually inside that bucket?
